# Using VARCHAR arrays in TSV

Tags: postgresql

I have a column of tags, called tags, which is an array type of varchars.
How can I modify this trigger to incorporate those words?

```
create
    trigger tsvectorupdate before insert
        or update
            on
            public.records for each row execute procedure tsvector_update_trigger( 'tsv',
            'pg_catalog.english',
            'title',
            'text',
            'caption',
            'location_name')
```

Comment: `array_to_string(tags, ',')` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

OK - the manual has the answer

```
CREATE function update_tsv() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
  new.tsv :=
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.title,'')), 'A') ||
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.caption,'')), 'A') ||
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.text,'')), 'A') ||
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.location_name,'')), 'A') ||
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', 
coalesce(array_to_string(new.tags,','),'')), 'A');
  return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON records FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_tsv();
```